# Use export default in .eslintrc.js file instead of module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, eslint, eslintrc

I would like to use `export default obj` instead of `module.exports = obj` in my `.eslintrc.js` file, because everywhere else in the codebase we are using `export`.

So far no luck, it was difficult to search for this problem.

The error I get:

```
> eslint src

Cannot read config file: src/.eslintrc.js
Error: Unexpected token export
src/.eslintrc.js:23
export default foo;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

Comment: eslintrc uses Node, Node doesn't support es6 exports. Perhaps you could run the Node process through a transpiler but this would be inefficient and nonsensical without a good reason

Comment: You might be able to get it to work with the `node --experimental-modules` flag, but I agree with Dominic that it's not really worth it.

Comment: @Dominic node *does* support ES6 modules as of 2022, all you have to do is add `"type": "module"` to your package.json

Answer (score 2):

### *UPDATE 2023:*

New configuration file (**`eslint.config.js`** instead of *`eslintrc`*) that is called ***flat** config*, now supports ESM:

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new#configuration-file

Sample:

https://github.com/raulmelo-articles/eslint-flat-config/blob/main/demos/basic-esm/eslint.config.js

---

#### *OLD ANSWER:*

Unfortunately:

> ESLint does not support ESM configuration at this time.

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#configuration-file-formats

[image: ESLint Configuration File Formats]

Answer (score 1):

To use the ES2015 syntax for default exports in an ESLint config file, one can use a combination of Babel for transpilation and Pirates for hooks to hijack a `require` statement that imports your ESLint config file written in ES2015. Allow me to explain.

Usually, ESLint will look for a `.eslintrc.js` file in the project root, and it usually is parsed by Node.js without Babel. We will be repurposing this file so that it does two things: registering a hook and importing the ES2015 ESLint config file.

Assuming you already have a `.eslintrc.js` using the ES2015 default export syntax, cut the contents out of that file and paste it into a new file named `.es2015lintrc.js` or similar. The name is irrelevant; it can be called anything you want.

```
// .es2015lintrc.js

export default {

// ESLint config properties...

}
```

Make sure you have the `@babel/preset-env`, `@babel/core`, `eslint`, and `pirates` packages installed before continuing. Next, create a file that defines your hook and its behavior. We'll call it `hook.js` for simplicity.

```
// hook.js

const {addHook} = require('pirates');
const {transform} = require('@babel/core');

module.exports = options =>
  addHook(
    function(source, filename) {
      return transform(source, {
        presets: [
          [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
              modules: 'cjs',
              targets: {
                node: process.versions.node
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      }).code;
    },
    {
      exts: ['.js'],
      ignoreNodeModules: true,
      ...options
    }
  );
```

Then import this module into the original `.eslintrc.js` using a `require` statement and register the hook that hijacks and transforms all files imported with future `require` statements. Finally, the ESLint config file written in ES2015 syntax can be imported using our hijacked `require` statement.

```
// .eslintrc.js

const registerHook = require('./hook');
registerHook();

module.exports = require('./.es2015lintrc').default;
```

Now you should be good to go! One can use this same method when writing a Babel config in ES2015 syntax too. Enjoy!

Comment: Also, you can just use a json. Don't know if it was something added in the last 2 years but...

```
{
  "extends": [ "./.eslint/linters.cjs" ]
}
```
And you can stick all your rules as cjs files in a .eslint folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have `@babel/register` installed, then just rename your `.eslintrc.js` to `.eslintrc.babel.js` (or whatever you like) and add this to `.eslintrc.js`:

```
require('@babel/register')
module.exports = require('./.eslintrc.babel.js').default
```